# Geopandas changing size of plot depending on axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gis, geopandas

This is throwing a wrench in all of my code. I'm trying to inset an Alaska axes among a larger continental plot using Axes.inset_axis([x0, y0, width, height]). But notice that, for the SAME x0/y0/width/height, I am getting a completely different returned Axes (size-wise), depending on what I set the axis limits of that plot to be:

**Default axis limits, which encompass the part of Alaska in the far Eastern Hemisphere:**

```
fig, continental_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
alaska_ax = continental_ax.inset_axes([.01, .01, .20, .28]) 

gdf.loc[['AK']].plot(column='cl', ax=alaska_ax)
```

[image: Default axis limits]

**Custom axis limits, which just encompass the parts of Alaska in the Western Hemisphere:**

```
fig, continental_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
alaska_ax = continental_ax.inset_axes([.01, .01, .20, .28]) # Same size and location parameters

gdf.loc[['AK']].plot(column='cl', ax=alaska_ax)

alaska_ax.set_xlim((-2.05*10**7, -1.42*10**7))
alaska_ax.set_ylim((6.38*10**6, 1.17*10**7))
```

[image: Custom axis limits]

So essentially, despite the same location specified, the bottom-left corner of the Alaska axis is in a different place. This would lead to problem if, say, I wanted to shift the one with default axis limits *down* even further -- I already have it specified as being 0.01 above the base of the parent axis...so I've run out of real estate.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'd be really appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: Ever find a solution? Im having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not, @user3711502. I just had to keep playing around with the inset_axes() bounds and even then it wasn't perfect. Sucks. My hunch is that it's something to do with geopandas, rather than matplotlib.